# Show div when textbox value is same as another div's content

Tags: javascript, html, show

I am making a quiz in which the answer will be random. I want the "Correct!" div to show when the textbox value is the same as another div.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttontest").click(function(){
        if ($('#full_day').val() == '#answer') {   
            $("#correct").show("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
        } 
        else {
            $("#correct").hide("fast");    //Slide Up Effect
            $("#incorrect").show("500").delay("1000").hide("500");
        }
    });
});
```

```
<p>What is the animal?</p>
<div id="correct">
    That's Correct!
</div>
<div id="incorrect">
    Sorry, Try again!
</div>
<div id="answer">Monkey</div>
<input type='text' id="full_day"/>
<input type='button' id="buttontest" value="clickme"/>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: basically keep the div tags property display none and ($('#full_day').val() == $('#answer').html())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($('#full_day').val() == $('#answer').text())
```

This is case sensitive. To make it case insensitive:

```
if ($('#full_day').val().toLowerCase() == $('#answer').text().toLowerCase())
```

Edit: As requested, here is a solution which allows multiple answers:

```
$('#check').bind('click', function() {
    var possibleAnswers = $('#answers').text().toLowerCase().split(' ');
    var givenAnswer = $('#user-answer').val().toLowerCase();
    var isAnswerCorrect = false;
    for (var indexPossibleAnswers = 0; indexPossibleAnswers < possibleAnswers.length; indexPossibleAnswers++)
    {
         if (possibleAnswers[indexPossibleAnswers] == givenAnswer)
         {
              isAnswerCorrect = true  
              break;
         }
    }
    if (isAnswerCorrect)
    {
         alert('Correct');   
    }
    else 
    {
         alert('Incorrect, try again.');   
    }
});
```

[Live demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/dislick/SrvNQ/)

Comment: Since `answer` is a `div` there is no `val` property... You should use `.text()` instead...

Comment: Is it possible to make it correct if the textbox value is the same as the div exept for one wourld? Let's say the div contains "animal pig", then only "pig" will give the "Correct!" div and "animal" will always be ignored?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear. The answer div will always contain "#loopriddle" due to the API I'm working with, so it will look like: 
<div id="answer">#loopriddle [correct answer]</div>I don't want the user to have to write #loopriddle to get the correct answer.

Comment: @user1890129 Can you show me an exact example of the #answer div so I can write a regular expression for it?

Comment: Just like this:
<div id="answer">#loopriddle The Silence of the Lambs</div>

Comment: @user1890129 Here is a jsfiddle for this case: http://jsfiddle.net/dislick/m2MEE/

Comment: @user1890129 You don't even need RegExp for this case, you could also just use `string.replace()` like this: `correctAnswer = correctAnswer.replace('#loopriddle ', '')`

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$('#answer').text()
```

instead of just

```
'#answer'
```

in the if statement.

Comment: can we get the text in between div tag like this ?

Comment: thats great. I had just an assumption in my mind, if I cant get value of a div, then not even text.

Comment: yes. for `<div id="answer">Monkey</div>` this `$('#answer').text()` should return "Monkey". **Here i added a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/btddn/**

Comment: Is it possible to make it correct if the textbox value is the same as the div exept for one wourld? Let's say the div contains "animal pig", then only "pig" will give the "Correct!" div and "animal" will always be ignored?

Comment: yes ... you could use something like `search()` or `indexOf()` to find the word in the longer string. or something more exciding like splitting the string into an array of substrings and compare them, depends a little also on what kind of answers you expect.

Comment: The answer div will always contain "#loopriddle", which I don't want the user to have to write in the answerbox to get it correct. What would be the code to always ignore "#loopriddle"?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttontest").click(function(){

        if ($('#full_day').val() == $('#answer').html()) {   
            $("#correct").show("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
        } 
        else {
            $("#correct").hide("fast");    //Slide Up Effect
            $("#incorrect").show("500").delay("1000").hide("500");
        }
    });
});

<p>What is the animal?</p>
<div id="correct" style="display:none;">
    That's Correct!
</div>
<div id="incorrect" style="display:none;">
    Sorry, Try again!
</div>
<div id="answer" style="display:none;">Monkey</div>
<input type='text' id="full_day"/>
<input type='button' id="buttontest" value="clickme"/>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it correct if the textbox value is the same as the div exept for one wourld? Let's say the div contains "animal pig", then only "pig" will give the "Correct!" div and "animal" will always be ignored?